# Django Python: How do I decrypt an AES-CTR mode encrypted file in the Python shell?

Tags: python, django, encryption, python-cryptography

I'm using https://github.com/eblocha/django-encrypted-files to encrypt files uploaded to a server through a simple contact form app in Django. `django-encrypted-files` uses AES in CTR mode to encrypt an uploaded file via an upload handler while streaming the file to the server.

What I'm trying to do is manually decrypt the encrypted file by downloading the file via FTP and decrypting it locally in the Python shell. I do not want or need to stream decrypt the file from the server or modify `django-encrypted-files`; I only want to manually download and then decrypt files locally in the Python shell.

The problem is I can't get local Python decryption to work. The docs at [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/?highlight=aes%20#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.Cipher) show an example of encryption and decryption using a sample text input in the Python shell. But there are no examples of encrypting/decrypting a file.

The code below what I'm trying to use in the Python shell. The original file uploaded via Django is uploaded_file.txt. The encrypted file downloaded from the server is encrypted.txt; the file to save the decrypted text to is decrypted.txt.

But when I try the code below, the decrypted.txt is empty. Is this an issue with writing the file? Or an issue with the `iv`?

What is a working example of decrypting a AES-CTR mode file in the local Python shell?

uploaded_file.txt: https://paste.c-net.org/MiltonElliot

encrypted.txt: https://paste.c-net.org/ChasesPrints

Python shell:

```
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
key = b'\x1a>\xf8\xcd\xe2\x8e_~V\x14\x98\xc2\x1f\xf9\xea\xf8\xd7c\xb3`!d\xd4\xe3+\xf7Q\x83\xb5~\x8f\xdd'
iv = os.urandom(16)
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CTR(iv))
decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
openfile = open("encrypted.txt", 'rb')
savefile = open("decrypted.txt", "wb")
read = openfile.read()
savefile.write(read[16:])
445 // output
exit
```

But the decrypted.txt file is empty.

---

This may or may not be relevant; this is the function that encrypts while streaming to the server:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from django.core.files.uploadhandler import FileUploadHandler

class EncryptedFileUploadHandler(FileUploadHandler):
    """Encrypt data as it is uploaded"""
    def __init__(self, request=None, key=None):
        super().__init__(request=request)
        self.key = key or settings.AES_KEY
    
    def new_file(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.nonce = os.urandom(16)
        self.encryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES(self.key),modes.CTR(self.nonce)).encryptor()
        self.nonce_passed = False
        return super().new_file(*args,**kwargs)

    def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
        if not self.nonce_passed:
            self.nonce_passed = True
            return self.nonce + self.encryptor.update(raw_data)
        else:
            return self.encryptor.update(raw_data)
    
    def file_complete(self, file_size):
        return
```

Comment: I don't see any decryption in the code. You just read *decrypt.txt* and write its content to *decrypted.txt* without the first 16 bytes. You output the first 16 bytes in the shell. At which point is the *Cryptography* library used? Also, post complete test data: key, (a short) plaintext and ciphertext.

Comment: Thanks! It could be that simple. Python newbie here. How do I make sure Python is using the Cryptography library?

Comment: You need to implement it, s. the [Cryptography docs](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/?highlight=aes%20#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.Cipher)

Comment: Ok, i.e. *import os* and *from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes* ?

Comment: Look at the link, implement the decryption analogously, but with CTR instead of CBC. Unless you post complete test data and a decryption code I can't help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During encryption, IV and ciphertext are concatenated: `IV || ciphertext`. During decryption, a random IV is used, which is wrong. Instead, the IV of the encryption must be applied. For this, IV and ciphertext have to be separated.
In addition, the `update()` and `finalize()` methods must be called, which perform the actual decryption.

The following code essentially matches your code, extended by the missing parts:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes

# Read ciphertext
openfile = open("encrypted.txt", 'rb')
read = openfile.read()
openfile.close()

# Separate IV and ciphertext; decrypt
iv = read[:16]
ciphertext = read[16:]
key = b'\x1a>\xf8\xcd\xe2\x8e_~V\x14\x98\xc2\x1f\xf9\xea\xf8\xd7c\xb3`!d\xd4\xe3+\xf7Q\x83\xb5~\x8f\xdd'
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CTR(iv))
decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
decrypted = decryptor.update(ciphertext) + decryptor.finalize()

# Store decrypted data
savefile = open("decrypted.txt", "wb")
savefile.write(decrypted)
savefile.close()
```

This code successfully decrypts the ciphertext in the linked file (using the posted key).

Comment: Thanks! I now see what I was doing wrong.

Comment: This is interesting; I found that this doesn't decrypt a zip file; I get "End-of-central-directory signature not found," and I had no luck using different methods of repairing the zip file before decryption. Have any idea where I should start to look for the issue? In the original uploader that encrypts the file? Thanks.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch - This can be due to many reasons, different algorithm, corrupted ciphertext, wrong key, etc. Please post a new question with all information needed to answer, especially test data, the encryption code or how the encrypted zip file was generated etc.

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake; zip files do encrypt/decrypt.